# How to dodge knife attacks?

Tags: batman-arkham-asylum

I am wondering how to succesfully dodge knife attacks. The "normal" approach of pressing <kbd>Y</kbd> does not work. Instead I stun the knife attackers by pressing <kbd>B</kbd> and hope to hit them fast enough KO via excessive <kbd>X</kbd> pressing. This assuming that I hit them first before they hit me though.

Hence: How am I supposed to dodge a knife attack once this glaringly red alarm icon appears?

Comment: I've deleted my answer as it was only relevant to Arkham City

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no direct counter to the knife goons in Arkham Asylum.

You may JUMP over them to continue your combo to another goon, or you can CAPE STUN them to open them up to direct attack.

A good strategy when fighting a group of enemies that contain 'special goons' ( knife and stun wielding ones ) is to build up your combo until you have a yellow move and do an instant takedown or body throw on the blade goons.

Answer (score 1):

My favourite is by far what tiddy mentioned, the instant takedown or throw to clean them up before you even get the "red alarm icon".

In a pinch, you might just want to use the invincibility you get from using these special moves. Don't hesitate to pick up unarmed thugs if you are about to lose a combo. You can also pre-emptively throw unarmed thugs *at* the armed ones.

In addition, you might be interested in dodging *away* from the knife weilding thugs (followed by batclawing them and jumping over them, or maybe engaging other thugs).